# How to override build command on Heroky

Tags: node.js, github, heroku, heroku-cli

I have an app that has a package with an older version of react. I know is not best practice but its for a proof of concept project.

I can't seem to find where I can override the build command on Heroku.

Earlier this year, Node.js deployments run "build" script automatically, but I am trying to avoid placing the override command on my package.json.

Does anyone know if its possible to override the build command on Heroku?

Comment: Nope. Not possible. You have to override your build command in the package.json because heroku does nothing else than run `npm run build`.

Comment: Specifically, what do you want to change about the build process?

Comment: I wanted to force the build. Downgraded the entire project and it built successfully. That's what I was trying to avoid, but had to be done. Thanks for the assist.